# C++ Dynamic Stack : typedeffing a pointer-struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, typedef

I can't understand what's happening on the beginning of this C++ code that would explain to me how to implement a stack using Dynamic Array. I'm sure the code is correct, because the program runs correctly (correct results), but I don't understand it!

```
struct Node {
    char Info;
    Node *Link;
};

typedef Node *Stack;
```

Let's see:

1. there is a `struct` called `Node`, and it has `Info` and `*Link` as "fields", like fields on a form paper. So `Node` is the name of a <del>"template"</del> (`struct`) with empty "fields". Each time we use `Node` on this program, like, let's say, `Node StackOverflow`, it's like photocopying this form paper and filling it's fields;
2. `*Link` is itself another `Node`! But how can a pointer ("*") part of a `struct` be another instance of the same `struct`? Pointers don't have "fields" like form papers! They can only have one address as value, so only one field, like any other variable. This code doesn't makes sense;
3. Then `*Stack` is `typedef`ined as a pointer ("*") that is a `struct` ("Node") that has a pointer inside ("*Link") that is really another struct ("Node *Link"). I don't understand anything anymore!!! HELP!

Comment: The pointer isn't an instance of a struct, it's a pointer to a struct.

Comment: Without using a pointer it would be impossible `struct Node { char Info; Node Link; };` You seem to think that the pointer version is the same as the non-pointer version. So I'm wondering whether you truly understand pointers.

Comment: *how to implement a stack* -- That looks like a Node that is part of a singly linked list to me, and not a stack.

Comment: @john `typedef Node *Stack` is then like `int *Stack` ?

Comment: No, in the first `Stack` is a typedef, in the second it is a variable. Although in both cases it's a pointer (typedef or variable).

Comment: Even though probably your idea in 1. is not too far off, the term "template" has a special meaning in C++ and isn't well suited for this kind of description.

Comment: @john Then `typedef Node *Stack` is telling that `*Stack` is a new data type that is a pointer to `Node` `structs` ?

Comment: Yes, almost. Strictly speaking it's not a new type, it's saying the types `Stack` and `Node*` are the same. So it's a new *name* for a type, not a new type.

Comment: And the new name is `Stack` not `*Stack` which isn't legal name for anything.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for noting. The study material presented this code as "Implementation of a Stack Using Dynamic Memory Allocation", so I can only suppose it's a Stack. But the same study material tells this kind of Stack bears resemblance with Linked Lists where insertions can be made only at the first position of the list.

Comment: Btw: In `typedef`s it can get confusing regarding where e.g. `*` belongs. This is why I prefer achieving the same effect with `using`: `using Stack = Node*;` Furthermore imho the `*` for pointers belongs to the type and isn't part of the variable: `Node::Link` has the type `Node*` and there's no need to use the `*` operator when using the variable name: `Node foo = ...; auto x = foo.Link;`

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Stack has a couple of meanings. Sounds like in your case it's the name of an Abstract Data Type (ADT) and a linked list implementation of that is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah `typedef Node *Stack;` -- The other issue is that when a programmer sees `Stack` in the program, it suggests that `Stack` is not actually a pointer, but a non-pointer type -- for example `void foo(Stack n);`.  This will cause confusion.  Better to not `typedef` this at all, and explicitly state `Node *` where appropriate within the program, so that everyone reading the code knows it is really a pointer.

Comment: @john The study material is about Stacks and Queues. There's one full implementation of each, first using Arrays, then using Dynamic Memory Allocation. So, 4 programs in total. I completely understood the implementations that uses Arrays, but I'm having trouble with the ones that uses Dynamic Memory Allocation, as you saw. But all 4 programs use Abstract Data Types, that were the content of the previous unit of the study material.

Comment: Dynamic allocation, linked lists and pointers, are hurdles that all new programmers have to jump over sooner or later.

Comment: @fabian Thanks for the alert. How would you rephrase 'item 1' so that it's less far off the Reality? Feel free to edit my question and improve 'item 1'.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah -- As to my comment on the typedef, a C++ programmer would create a `Stack` class, where a member variable is a `Node *`.  Then public member functions of `Stack` would be `push`, `pop`, etc. that manage the `Node *` properly.  Unfortunately, the goal of your course material seems not to be on C++ programming style and idioms, but on data structures.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The program code here has 5 other functions besides `main` : `Initialization`, `IsEmpty`, `IsFull`, `Push`, and `Pop` (no `Peek`). But `class` is something not yet studied. The course is a graduation discipline called "Algorithms and Data Structures I".

Comment: @john If `typedef Node *Stack;` is "saying the types `Stack` and `Node*` are the same", like you said, then it means that this line on `main` function is creating a pointer without using asterisk: `Stack Top;` ?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Yes that's right. And that's why some people don't like this style. It's good to know where your pointers are, so it's bad that you can create a pointer without using an asterisk. At least that's how the argument goes. (Paul McKenzie made the same argument)

Comment: @john Thank you for all your helpful comments. Now I understand what @PaulMcKenzie said about "it suggests that `Stack` is not actually a pointer, but a non-pointer type".

Comment: @fabian I appreciate that you indicated `using` as more readable than `typedef`. But there is no `using` on my study material, so I better not risk to use it wrongly, correct?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah You need to judge yourself, whether it's a good idea to consult additional sources to extend your C++ beyond what's (currently) taught to you in your study material. If you're attending a class, and you're working on  homework assignment, your results may not get accepted, if you go too far, but if you want to learn more en.cppreference.com is one of, if not the best resource out there: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias (Works as lookup, but not as tutorial though.)

Comment: @fabian Thank you for the hyperlink. I'm not on a class. The teacher is more like my boss than my teacher, so he provided me with the succint material, but studying is up to me. And I'm studying for a Master Degree Selective Proccess that is just an exam on Algorithms and Data Structures. I need not to show extreme knowledge, just be correct on 1/3 of the questions. So I'd better not risk making elaborate incorrect programs instead of basic correct programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the code.

```
struct Node {
    char Info;
    Node *Link;
};

typedef Node * Stack;
```

And you wrote this:

> there is a struct called Node, and it has Info and *Link as "fields",
> like fields on a form paper. So Node is the name of a "template"
> (struct) with empty "fields". Each time we use Node on this program,
> like, let's say, Node StackOverflow, it's like photocopying this form
> paper and filling it's fields;

That's close. You don't have a `* Link`, you have a `Link` field, which is a pointer to another node. This is an important concept called a linked list. The first item points to the second one, and that one points to the third one, et cetera. (It can also be used for so many more things).

So you can do something like this:

```
 Node myNode;
 myNode.Info = 'A';
 myNode.Link = nullptr;
```

You now have a linked list with exactly one item, and it's Info is 'A'.

You can then do this:

```
 Node * anotherNode = new Node();
 myNode.Link = anotherNode;
 anotherNode->Info = 'B';
 anotherNode->Link = nullptr;
```

Now you have a linked list with two items, with values 'A' and 'B'.

> *Link is itself another Node! But how can a pointer ("*") part of a struct be another instance of the same struct? Pointers don't have
> "fields" like form papers! They can only have one address as value, so
> only one field, like any other variable. This code doesn't makes
> sense;

No. The field is called `Link` and it is of type `Node *`. That is, it's a pointer to another node.

> Then *Stack is typedefined as a pointer ("*") that is a struct
> ("Node") that has a pointer inside ("*Link") that is really another
> struct ("Node *Link"). I don't understand anything anymore!!! HELP!

This is the same confusion. The type is `Stack` and it is an alias for `Node *`. That is -- a Stack is a pointer to a Node object.

So these two lines of code are exactly the same:

```
 Node * nodePtr1 = nullptr;
 Stack  nodePtr2 = nullptr;
```

Both of them define a `Node *` that are initialized to nullptr.

Comment: I'd like to recommend, to other people who will land here with confusions like mine, that https://pythontutor/cpp.html was much better at illustrating what happens during execution than the Code::Blocks debugger.